# Accessing Gmail atom feed using oAuth in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail

I have send a request to server to get the atom feed using the OAuth but unfortunately I got `http 401 Error` Authentication Failed after each request.  Please find the code below for reference:

```
-(void)loadOAuthRequest:(NSString*)authToken
{
    NSString *accessToken=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer=%@",authToken];
    NSString *gmailAPI = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/";
    NSLog(@"%@",gmailAPI);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:gmailAPI];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];    
    NSLog(@"Access token : %@",accessToken);
    [request setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request   delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}
```

This is what I used but I got the following error like this below:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
```

Can any one please tell me how to send a request to the server to get the gmail content using the OAuth access token.